# Visual Studio - Control Window Positioning with Hotkey

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way (or plugin) that would allow me to modify how the windows are embedded into eachother?  For instance, let's say I have a window like this:

[image]

I want to be able to press a hotkey (e.g. Ctrl + Right Arrow) to make the current window split and go to the right, like this:

[image]

I'm basically envisioning a situation just like the later Windows OS' where you can press Win+Arrow to move windows around the screen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way.

Just go to `Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard`.

Now there are essentially four commands that you can bind to your keyboard shortcuts:

```
Window.NewHorizontalTabGroup
Window.NewVerticalTabGroup
Window.MovetoNextTabGroup
Window.MovetoPreviousTabGroup
```

You can even assign your own shortcuts to

```
Window.Float
Window.FloatAll
Window.MoveToMainDocumentGroup
```

as well if you want.

The `Window.Move...` commands are in a way the "undo commands" of the `Window.New...` and `Window.Float...` ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the **Window** - **New Vertical Tab Group** menu command or assign a shortcut to the **Window.NewVerticalTabGroup** keyboard command.

Comment: No answer since 13 hours and then suddenly two similar answers within two minutes. That's really funny sometimes.  ;-)